# Custom Exception in Dart programming language

Tags: dart

I created a custom exception called `DepositeException` and trying to access its custom exception message `(errorMessage)` in `main` method but it's throwing error. What might be the problem in following code.

```dart
void main() {
  try {
    depositAmount(-100);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.errorMessage());
  }
}

class DepositException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    return "you cannot enter amount less then 0";
  }
}

void depositAmount(int amount) {
  if (amount < 0) {
    throw new DepositException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because ~~exception catching in Dart is unchecked~~ the exception type is unspecified so it will return Object (thanks to @jamesdlin for the correction).

To catch the custom exception, you need specify the type like this:

```dart
try{
  depositAmount(-100);
} on DepositException catch (e){
    print(e.errorMessage());
}
```

Reference:

- [How to create a custom exception and handle it in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855288/16316973)

Comment: The code is right, but the reasoning a bit inaccurate.  It's not that exception catching is unchecked, and `catch (e)` *does* catch the exception, but since no type is specified, it has a static type of `Object`, so the `errorMessage()` method isn't known.